# How to represent elements in table component

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to create a table like Angular component. It will look like the component on the image bellow.

[image]

Each element can have different colors. When the user of this component clicks on a element, the component shoudl return the elements value through @Output.
What I'm struggling with is how should the data representation look like?

My first idea was to represent it as a simple array:

```
[
[["low", "21", "yellow"], ["low", "< 21", "yellow"], ["low", "> 300", "green"]],
[["medium", "21", "yellow"], ["medium", "< 21", "yellow"], ["medium", "> 300", "green"]],
[["high", "21", "red"], ["high", "< 21", "orange"], ["high", "> 300", "orange"]]
]
```

But then I noticed, that I should represent an element rather as an object than only a three string values:

```
[{val1: "low", val2: "21", hexColor: "ededed"}]
```

But then again, I need to somehow know which element is selected, to properly display it in UI, so I decided to add another property to the object.

```
[{val1: "low", val2: "21", hexColor: "ededed", selected: false}]
```

Since I don't have much experience, I'm wondering if is there a better way to represent the state of this component, like I did in above examples.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the most practical way is to have an array of objects with each object representing a row in your table, and each property of that object representing a cell of that row.

So your object would look something like this (check `tableData` property of the component class below).

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export interface CustomElement {
  name: string;
  col1: string;
  col2: string;
  col3: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  tableData: CustomElement[] = [
    { name: 'low', col1: 'yellow',col2: 'yellow', col3:'green' },
    { name: 'high', col1: 'yellow', col2: 'yellow', col3: 'yellow' },
    { name: 'medium', col1: 'red', col2: 'orange', col3: 'orange' },
  ];

  toggleSelection({ target }, element) {
    console.log(element);
    target.classList.toggle('selected');
  }
}
```

A pretty basic setup to display this data could be something like this below.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="cell"></th>
            <th class="cell">21</th>
            <th class="<21</th> 
            <th class="cell"> >300</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let element of tableData">
            <td>{{element.name}}</td>
            <td [ngStyle]="{'background-color': element.col1}" class="cell" (click)="toggleSelection($event, element)"></td>
            <td [ngStyle]="{'background-color': element.col2}" class="cell" (click)="toggleSelection($event, element)"></td>
            <td [ngStyle]="{'background-color': element.col3}" class="cell" (click)="toggleSelection($event, element)"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If you are you displaying if a cell is selected you don't really need a property to store this information, you could just add a class (`selected` as shown below) when the cell is clicked. But if you actually need that information for some specific logic than just add the property to the object.

```css
.selected {
  border: 2pt solid gray;
}

.selected::after {
  content: '✔️'
}
```

Check a working demo in this stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-custom-table).

Answer (score 0):

I have created stackblitz app https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4ogdgy

```
<table border="1">
 <tr *ngFor="let row of colorArray>
      <td *ngFor="let item of row trackBy: $index" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': item[2]}" (click)="selectedCell(item)">
        {{ item }}
      </td>
</tr>
  </table>
```

console.log('at component ---->', 'You will see your item', item);

let me know if this is full fills your requirement. You can do the same thing with array of objects. I think this enough to give you the idea